# How to run a dart program with big memory?

Tags: memory, dart

I'm trying to read a very big file(more than 1G) in a dart program, but it throws out of memory exception.

How do I configure the command line to make it run with a bigger memory? Just like:

```
 -Xmx1G
```

in Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The VM has a flag to increase the heap size: `--old_gen_heap_size`. For example `--old_gen_heap_size=1024` would set it to 1GB.

This flag is among the developer-flags and is not considered stable. It could change or go away.