# Why Dart goes very slow after some time?

Tags: memory, garbage-collection, dart, freeze

We have some problems with Dart. It seems like after some period of time the garbage collector can't clear the memory in VM, so application hangs. Anyone with this issue? Are there any memory limits?

Comment: I haven't seen any similar reports yet. Have you tried to use Observatory https://www.dartlang.org/tools/observatory/ to investigate?

Answer (score 2):

You should reuse your objects instead of creating new ones. You should use pool pattern:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern

Be careful about canvas and it's proper destruction.

Another GC performance papers:

http://blog.tojicode.com/2012/03/javascript-memory-optimization-and.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-performance.html

Comment: Reusing objects in not always beneficial. The Dart VM (as well as V8) use generational GCs. Cleaning up short-lived objects is very fast. However, tracking pointers from old to new space is expensive. If you keep reusing objects they are migrated to the old generation. If you now allocate new objects and add pointers to the old objects you will slow down the program because the VM needs to track those dependencies.

Comment: Good point. I have this problem with canvas elements. Canvas elements in app weren't destroyed properly. Finally we have improved canvas destruction instead of reusing canvases.

Comment: @FlorianLoitsch Nice to know! But is there a way to help VM manage persistent objects better? For example, what if they have top level final reference then they can't be theoretically removed and VM should optimize them (move to persistent memory) ?

Comment: Most things happen automatically. If your object survives longer it goes into the old-space area. Having a pointer from old-space to new-space doesn't mean that the new object will survive very long. Your pool-pattern example is a good counter example. In general it's just a good idea to allocate things at the same time if they die together.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any memory limits?

Yes.  Dart apparently runs with a maximum sizes that can be configured at launch time:

- [How to run a dart program with big memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519462/how-to-run-a-dart-program-with-big-memory)

(The following applies to all garbage-collected languages ...)

If your application starts to run out of space (i.e. the heap is slowly filing with objects that the GC can't remove) then you may get into a nasty situation where the GC runs more and more frequently, and manages to reclaim less and less memory each time.  Eventually you run out of memory, but before that happens the application gets really slow.

The solution is typically to do one or both of the following:

- Find what is causing the memory to run out.  It is typically not that you are allocating too many objects.  Rather, the typical cause is that the unwanted objects are all still reachable ... via some data structure that your application has built.
- Set the "quick death" tuning option for the GC .... if available.  For example, Java garbage collectors can be configured to measure the time spent garbage collecting.  (The GC overhead.)  When the GC overhead exceeds a preset ratio, the Java virtual machine throws an `OutOfMemoryError` to "pull the plug".